# How to filter multiple select values?

Tags: jquery

I'm using selectpicker with fullcalendar, I've created a filter which works well with single values, but I can't make it works with selectpicker...

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/odfOSlVZMJppLK68nIsU?p=preview)

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
 var zone_class = event.className.toString();

return ['all', zone_class].indexOf($('#zones_filter').val()) >= 0;

},
```

How can I add multiple values in the return?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to make it work with multiple values?

Comment: Yes, i want to make it work with the selectpicker - i named it "Multiple values"

Comment: Ok, gimme a minute

Comment: And here it goes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152825/1681154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set `value` on your `option`s:

```
        <select title="Vacances scolaires" id="zones" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit"
                multiple="" style="display: none;" name="vacances[]">
            <option value='all' selected>All zones</option>
            <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-zone-a" value="zone_a">Zone A</option>
            <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-zone-b" value="zone_b">Zone B</option>
            <option data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-zone-c" value="zone_c">Zone C</option>
        </select>
```

Then you need to subscribe to your `selectpicker`:

```
$('#zones').on('change',function(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});
```

And finally you need to check if your selection includes your class or `all`:

```
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
    const zone_class = event.className.toString();

    const selectedValues = $('#zones').val();

    return selectedValues.includes('all') 
      || selectedValues.includes(zone_class);
  }
```

Check [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VWoI2xfE2I3VMh9y3DDn?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks - how can i set the "All" option to be the default? when load - all the events disappears

Comment: By using standard HTML - `selected` attribute, like so - `<option value='all' selected>All zones</option>`.

Comment: Thanks - i get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null" - i guess the selectedValues returns null

Comment: @RoyBarOn can you provide the Plunk where you are getting this? Also let me know the browser type and version you are using.

Comment: I'm getting the error in the Development - not on plunker  - i guess it's caused by selectedValues.includes() returns null while unchecking all

Comment: Fixed added if(selectedValues == null){
                             return false;
                         }

Answer (score 1):

Ok, After observing your code, I found multiple things that you missed.

1. Multiple Selector wasn't provided with values attribute
2. It's `<label>` not `<lable>`

So to begin I added an `id="multi_zones"` and values within the options on your Multiple Selector select.

And updated this:

```
  eventRender: function(event, element) {
     var zone_class = event.className.toString();

   return ['all', zone_class].some(e => $('#multi_zones').val().indexOf(e) >= 0)

  },
```

And updated the caller:

```
$('#multi_zones').on('change',function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
})
```

Working [plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/OgV60hBChYRJdTH7BEYz?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks - i get an error once the  $('#multi_zones').val().indexOf(e) is null, any idea how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
   var zone_class = event.className.toString();

   return ['all', zone_class].some(e => $('#zones_filter').val().indexOf(e) >= 0)
},
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried it with the selectpicker but it doesn't worked, i changed it to eventRender: function(event, element) {
     var zone_class = event.className.toString();

   return ['all', zone_class].some(e => $('#zones').val().indexOf(e) >= 0)

  },



});

  $('#zones').on('change',function(){
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            })